# Google VR SDK and Wikitude conflicts (duplicate symbols).

Tags: ios, wikitude

I'm working on an iOS (10) app which includes an AR component through the [WikiTude](http://wikitude.com/) library and Google 360 video using the [GVDSDK (Google VR SDK)](https://developers.google.com/vr/ios/). The two libraries seem incompatible with each other. If I include the Wikitude framework in my project (without actually using it) and build for device, everything works except when it tries to render the first frame of video I get a fatal error (see below). This can be replicated by downloading the GVRSDK video example project, adding the Wikitude framework and then running the app.

The only clue I get as to a conflict is when building for the simulator, I get duplicate symbol warnings (see below). The duplicate symbol warnings with references to the GoogleVR Library and Wikitdude

Example (although there are many of these (see below)
`/Users/mortocks/Repos/BH360/Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libCardboardSDK_x86_64.a(json_value.o)
 /Users/mortocks/Repos/BH360/WikitudeSDK.framework/WikitudeSDK(libCommonLibrary.a-x86_64-master.o)`

I've read up on [how to remove duplicate symbols](http://atnan.com/blog/2012/01/12/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-errors-during-linking-by-removing-classes-from-static-libraries) from libraries using lipo and ar command line tools and I was able to do this but how to I diagnose which symbols are the issue. For example I've tried removing libCommonLibrary.a-x86_64-master.o from Wikitude (hoping in was a "system common" library) but that caused many dependancy issues. Also, using the example above I can find json_value.o in libCardboardSDK_armv7 but not in the Wikitude SDK so I'm not sure what to remove.

Any help/education on how to fix or diagnose the problem would be GREATLY appreciated.

---

**FATAL ERROR WHEN RENDERING FRAME**

`` (lldb) bt
* thread #25: tid = 0x3fe32, 0x000000018bc96f40 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_memmove + 320, name = 'com.google.cardboard.RenderThread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1471cabb0)
  * frame #0: 0x000000018bc96f40 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_memmove + 320
    frame #1: 0x0000000100368858 BH360`mem_read + 100
    frame #2: 0x000000010072c224 BH360`unz64local_getByte + 52
    frame #3: 0x000000010072bfc4 BH360`unz64local_getLong + 48
    frame #4: 0x000000010072b074 BH360`unz64local_GetCurrentFileInfoInternal + 128
    frame #5: 0x000000010072b65c BH360`unzGoToFirstFile + 72
    frame #6: 0x0000000100368e70 BH360`unzAttach + 448
    frame #7: 0x0000000100360a4c BH360`ion::base::ZipAssetManager::RegisterAssetData(void const*, unsigned long) + 68
    frame #8: 0x000000010028ad5c BH360`ion::base::OnceFlag::CallChecked(std::__1::function<bool ()> const&) + 16
    frame #9: 0x000000010028f8cc BH360`void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void>::__call<std::__1::__bind<void (&)(std::__1::function<bool ()> const&), bool (*)()>&>(std::__1::__bind<void (&)(std::__1::function<bool ()> const&), bool (*)()>&&&) + 80
    frame #10: 0x0000000100292c68 BH360`vr::VideoTextureRenderable::SetupShaderProgram(ion::base::SharedPtr<ion::gfxutils::ShaderManager> const&, ion::base::SharedPtr<ion::gfx::ShaderInputRegistry> const&) + 284
    frame #11: 0x00000001002927a4 BH360`vr::VideoTextureRenderable::VideoTextureRenderable(ion::base::SharedPtr<ion::gfxutils::ShaderManager> const&, ion::base::SharedPtr<ion::gfx::Renderer> const&, vr::VideoTextureRenderable::TextureType, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > const&, ion::math::Matrix<3, float> const&, ion::base::SharedPtr<ion::gfx::Shape>, bool) + 1136
    frame #12: 0x00000001002920a0 BH360`std::__1::shared_ptr<vr::VideoTextureRenderable> std::__1::shared_ptr<vr::VideoTextureRenderable>::make_shared<ion::base::SharedPtr<ion::gfxutils::ShaderManager>&, ion::base::SharedPtr<ion::gfx::Renderer>&, vr::VideoTextureRenderable::TextureType, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >&, ion::math::Matrix<3, float>&, ion::base::SharedPtr<ion::gfx::Shape>&, bool const&>(ion::base::SharedPtr<ion::gfxutils::ShaderManager>&&&, ion::base::SharedPtr<ion::gfx::Renderer>&&&, vr::VideoTextureRenderable::TextureType&&, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >&&&, ion::math::Matrix<3, float>&&&, ion::base::SharedPtr<ion::gfx::Shape>&&&, bool const&&&) + 176
    frame #13: 0x0000000100291ee8 BH360`vr::VideoRenderableBuilder::Build() + 188
    frame #14: 0x0000000100291734 BH360`vr::PanoVideoRenderer::SetVideoTexture(std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > const&, ion::math::Matrix<3, float> const&) + 252
    frame #15: 0x00000001001a1270 BH360`-[GVRVideoView drawAtTime:] + 620
    frame #16: 0x00000001001a3f5c BH360`-[GVRWidgetView render:] + 596
    frame #17: 0x000000010019bc70 BH360`-[GVRWeakRenderTarget render:] + 76
    frame #18: 0x000000010019cd28 BH360`-[GVRRenderLoop updateWithDisplayLink:] + 236
    frame #19: 0x00000001022cbb1c GPUToolsCore`-[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 176
    frame #20: 0x000000018fe0f640 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch(unsigned long long) + 44
    frame #21: 0x000000018fe0f4ec QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 444
    frame #22: 0x000000018ce78570 IOKit`IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 372
    frame #23: 0x000000018cba256c CoreFoundation`__CFMachPortPerform + 180
    frame #24: 0x000000018cbba934 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
    frame #25: 0x000000018cbba0e8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436
    frame #26: 0x000000018cbb7bcc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1840
    frame #27: 0x000000018cae6048 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
    frame #28: 0x000000018cb338d4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRun + 112
    frame #29: 0x000000018d6f250c Foundation`__NSThread__start__ + 1024
    frame #30: 0x000000018bc9f860 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 240
    frame #31: 0x000000018bc9f770 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 284
    frame #32: 0x000000018bc9cdbc libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 4
(lldb) ``

Comment: I've got the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?